# @Input() variables is missing after recompiling on Angular 9

Tags: angular, synchronization, angular9

Today I've faced a issue that when my angular application recompiles, the @Input() variables misses their values and shows blank to HTML. I tried a couple of times to debug, but it wasn't enough. After changing it to non-Input variable, the value shows properly, but I need the @Input() to get the value from Parent.

HTML:

```
<div class="title" [ngClass]="{'not-applicable': item.status === 6}">{{item.template}}</div>
```

Typescript:

```
@Input() template = 1;
```

[This image show that the text is blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr8eO.png)

Comment: you need pass to the children as [template]="item.template" (I imagine, because your code not show clearly the problem)

Comment: Please show us the entire code how you pass the value to the custom component, as well as the (relevant) code of the custom component. If not, we can only guess what the problem may be. Your best bet at this point is what @Eliseo stated.

Comment: it worked here.. Thanks guys!